# What does this "subset" symbol mean?

Tags: notation

I just came across this "subset" symbol in a PDF:

$$\Omega \subsetneq T$$

I've never seen it before, and I tried looking for it via Detexify (to no avail). What does it mean?

Comment: [subset definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#Definitions)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This means $\Omega$ is a *proper* subset of $T$. That is, $\Omega\subseteq T$ but $\Omega \neq T$.

For example, $\{1, 2, 3\}\subsetneq \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$.

Comment: @gablin: Another variant is $\subsetneqq$, and of course some folks use $\subset$ to mean proper subset.

Comment: Argh, the author mixes the various notations throughout the document! Why not just pick one and be consistent...

Answer (score 12):

$\subsetneq$ ($\text{"\\subsetneq"}$) means:  subset, but not equal.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f%27s_theorem)'s a nice example:

> Let Ω be a half-strip in the complex plane:
>   $$
>     \Omega = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | x_1 \leq \mathrm{Re} (z) \leq x_2 \text{ and } \mathrm{Im} (z) \geq y_0 \} \subsetneq \mathbb{C}. \, $$